# How do I execute .jar java program on Windows 7 command line?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, command-line, yui

I have been looking things up online and could not find a good answer so far. I want to execute the YUI compressor tool to obfuscate/minify my javascript file. I do have JRE installed.

It looks like the file association is fine as you can see here:

```
C:\directory\tempFiles>assoc .jar
    .jar=jarfile
```

I set up file association using ftype:

```
C:\directory\tempFiles>ftype jarfile
     jarfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

The compressor tool is saved as a .jar file and is called "yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar"

When I try to run the .jar file, the cmd kept saying that the word 'java' is not recognized as an internal command... this is how I run it:

```
C:\directory\tempFiles\yuicompressor-2.4.6\build>java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar [options] [input file]
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: steps are below to make it easy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the JDK / JRE bin folder path to your PATH. See [here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html).

Answer (score 3):

**How to run jar files**

Open Command Prompt.

Run one of the below given command.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin>javaw.exe -jar D:\yourfile.jar

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin>java -jar D:\yourfile.jar
```

Easy.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable PATH needs to include JAVA_HOME/bin. This is usually done automatically when installing a JDK with a windows installer package.

However, if you only install the JRE - which is actually all you need, you need to mage the changes to the PATH variable manually

Answer (score 0):

Java comes up with jar extractor... so you can just go in bin folder and paste the jar file there.

then go to command prompt....
go to to the bin directory then use the following command:

```
jar xf jar-file (name of your jar file)
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: ...and this does what? What is its purpose? What does it accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Create a batch file (ie: script.bat) and place it inside of this folder:

C:\Users{user}\Downloads\yuicompressor-2.4.7\yuicompressor-2.4.7\build

**Step 2**

Then put all of the JavaScript files you want to combine and the output file name of the combined file inside of your script.bat file:

java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar droplinemenu.js effects.js jquery-1.4.4.min.js jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js --type js -o combined.js

**Step 3**

Run ***script.bat*** as Administrator

Answer (score -1):

My solution using a combination of the answers above, 
my goal was to start a .jar file which is named CombatLogReader.jar, along with the game 
Star Trek Online.exe via a command prompt. 
at first i was typeing in Start "" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Star Trek Online\CombatLogReader\CombatLogReader.jar"  but the file would not start, while researching why i could start the file manualy but not via cmd. my research got me here,

i modified my bat file to point to the java directory

This is how my bat file looks

```
@echo off
rem Star Trek Online
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Star Trek Online\Star Trek Online.exe" 
rem CombatLogReader
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"
javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Star Trek Online\CombatLogReader\CombatLogReader.jar"
exit
```

and it works, now every thing i need starts with just one icon 
the command prompt dose stay open untell combatlogreader is clsoed, but it dose not interupt the operation of any thing

Kudo's to everyone, who posted niplets of answers,

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved if you cut out all of the game related stuff and the stuff that didn't work, so the answer is focused on just what fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this and it worked, I simply copied my java file to the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin since I had installed JDK 7 and since I am running a 64bit machine: Yours could be C:\Program Files\Java\jreX\bin depending on which X version of java you are running.

I then fired up the command prompt, ran as administrator and simply changed directory to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin by typing at the command prompt:

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

This changes the directory to the above directory at the command prompt, I then ran:
java -jar myjavaprogram.jar

Lo and behold my java executable file fired up.
The error was because the system could not find the java.exe in the folder your coomand prompt is currently in so you need to change that to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin depending on which version of java you have installed and which bit of machine you are running.

Comment: -1  Do not put your source files in the directories of the JRE!