# Java weird behaviour. .jar can't be opened

Tags: java, windows, runtime

Whenever I try to double-click a .jar file, it gives me a message saying that it can't locate or load the main class of the file. However, if I try to open the .jar file in the command line like this:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

Then, it runs. Is it something wrong the the system variables or something? I'm having a lot of trouble with java and uninstalling and reinstalling it again doesn't seem to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

EXTRA INFO: I'm running on Win7 64-bit, with both JDK 7 Update 9 (64-bit) and Java 7 Update 9 (64-bit). It also used to run .jar files just by double-clicking before, I don't know what happened.

Comment: What happens when you double-click the JAR on your particular system is up to your particular system. The best anyone can do is enumerate the ways you can look that up for yourself.

Comment: Have you gone through the instructions from this [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084984/how-do-i-execute-jar-java-program-on-windows-7-command-line)?

Comment: are there other jars that run as part of this program, or just a single jar?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's not a very useful answer, but ok.

Comment: @eis Thanks, lemme take a look

Comment: @jtahlborn the jar is the whole program, it doesn't need other files to run. The proof is that it runs with the command java -jar file.jar

Comment: @eis Eis, I read the thread you sent me and it is about running java on the command line, which I know how to do and specifically did, as told in the thread we are currently commenting. I want to run the jar file just by double-clicking it. It used to work before, I don't know what's happened.

Comment: @Richard the way it's explained there should make it work also when double clicking. The point is that if you configure the env so that you don't need to type `java -jar` prefix, it should work equally well by double clicking as well as just typing "jarfilename.jar".

Comment: the reason i asked about other jars is that relative paths may work when run from the command line but not when double-clicking.  so the fact that it works from the command line is not proof that no other jars are required.

Answer (score 3):

Check that these two configurations are in place:

```
C:\>assoc .jar
    .jar=jarfile

C:\>ftype jarfile
     jarfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

With the latter pointing to the correct location of your javaw.exe. It should work then.

Comment: I'd +2 this if I could.  I've never seen the ftype command before.

Comment: Both are working, except you Program Files (x86) part is actually only Program Files and it's not jre6, it's jre7.

Comment: @Richard well that's environment specific. That's why I told "the latter pointing to the correct location...". So are you sure it is the correct place where it is pointing at?

Comment: So if you take the output of that conf, say `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1"`, put your jar file in the place of `%1`, and run the output manually, it works?

Comment: Ok. There's also this [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64) about a similar issue, check that out, too.

Comment: Ok, I did the association to the javaw.exe and tried to open with it, but now, not only it pops up the black cmd screen, now it does nothing. Should it be javaw instead of only java?

Comment: I just tested with the java.exe instead of the javaw.exe you told me, just and it gave me the popup black cmd screen with the error.

Comment: @Richard maybe you missed the parameters at the end of the string, or any quotes along the way.

Comment: Where could I have missed it?

Comment: @eis Help me please? I think we are almost solving the problem

Comment: @Richard by parameters I meant if you accidentally wiped out those `"%1" %*` in the process. They should've been added automatically, but one never knows. `ftype` will tell you. If else fails, you could try removing all java installations and then installing just one of them, and after that re-check the stuff we've been talking about. Don't have other ideas beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

Double clicking on the jar in Win7 won't pass the -jar flag to the java program, so nothing will happen.

Comment: But something **does** happen for OP, and that something happens precisely when you invoke `java -jar`.

Comment: It used to work before. How can I set it to do the command java -jar x.jar automatically?

Comment: Exactly Marko, that's what's troubling me

Comment: I was a bit loose with "nothing will happen": it fails to run the jar which is definitely not nothing.  OPs comment here that it used to work is entirely new information though.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to write about that. Editing original post.

Comment: @David How about "it gives me a message saying that it can't locate or load the main class of the file"?